# google.load - and message "google is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api

What do I need to include to do a `google.load()` statement? 
I'm getting the error:

```
google is not defined
```

Based on [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#DetailedDocumentation) page, I thought I should add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG">
</script>
```

But when I did, I got this error:

```
"window.LoadFirebugConsole" is not a function.
```

Comment: I can't define google, but I know it when I see it. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function LoadGoogle()
    {
        if(typeof google != 'undefined' && google && google.load)
        {
            // Now you can use google.load() here...
        }
        else
        {
            // Retry later...
            setTimeout(LoadGoogle, 30);
        }
    }

    LoadGoogle();
</script>
```

The idea is to **retry until google is defined**.

The other solutions didn't help me, probably because this piece of code is loaded via Ajax from another page.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. You have to use the new JS library described in the answer by Whitehat here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829721/google-charts-a-parser-blocking-cross-site-is-invoked-via-document-write

Answer (score 9):

Did you include the google jsapi script before adding the load and callback methods? They should be in seperate script blocks.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        
    google.load("jquery", "1");

    // Define our onLoad callback
    function OnLoad(){
      alert("Loaded!");
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

There are additional examples in the [Google's 'AJAX Api's Playground'](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jquery).

Comment: This can easily happen e.g. when Wordpress template uses google but before including google api and after that includes the same second time - just comment the first appearance and keep the one AFTER the google api include :)

Answer (score 5):

you should include this script -- http://www.google.com/jsapi

Answer (score 5):

I had the problem, but I was using:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" />`

It was solved by chanching the line to:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`