# Google Charts: A Parser-blocking, cross site is invoked via document.write

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I get the above message when I try and load a Google Charts script.

I'm pretty sure the issue is that I'm trying to load the dataTable using jQuery's `getJSON` method, but I've read through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556406/google-setonloadcallback-with-jquery-document-ready-is-it-ok-to-mix) and still can't connect the dots.

The data I'm trying to get comes from the url `/api/formula` and looks like this:

```
[{"name": "the name", "amount": "the amount"},{...},{...}]
```

The script I use for the charts is this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
'packages':['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function loadIngredients() {
var jsonData = {
 "cols": [
 {"id":"","label":"Ingredient","pattern":"","type":"string"},
 {"id":"","label":"Amount","pattern":"","type":"number"}
 ],
 "rows": []
};

$.getJSON('/api/formula', function(data){
  $.each(data, function(key, item){
    jsonData.rows.push({"c":[{"v":item.name,"f":null},{"v":item.amount,"f":null}]});
  });
});
return jsonData;
}

function drawChart() {
  var options = {
    'title': 'Formula Breakdown By Weight',
    'pieHole': 0.4
  };

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(loadIngredients());
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('formula-chart-div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And finally the jQuery I nest it inside looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.formula-info').click(function(){


if (someStuffIsntEntered) {
    $('#modal2').modal();
} else if(someOtherStuffIsntEnered) {
    $('#modal3').modal();
} else {
  $('#formula-info-div').fadeIn(750);
  $('#formula-build-div').hide();

  //draw chart from formula-chart.js
  loadIngredients();


  //grab json data for formula ingredients
  $.getJSON('/api/formula', function(data){
    $('.formula-breakdown-table > tbody').empty();
    //fill in table with info provided in form at top of page
    $.each(data, function(key, item){
    //fill in a table with data from the JSON
    );
  });
 }
});

//fade in top of page
    $('.back-to-main-page').click(function(){
    $('#formula-build-div').fadeIn(750);
    $('#formula-info-div').hide();
  });
});
```

And if it helps the files are loaded in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="../../../javascripts/formula.js"></script> //jquery
<script src="../../../javascripts/formula-chart.js"></script> //google charts
```

There might be a few things wrong with my code, but I believe my error message is because the data itself isn't being loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a few issues here, i'll try to help...

---

first, need to use the latest version of google charts, according to the release notes...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement...

use this --> `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

```
google.charts.load('current', {
'packages': ['corechart']
});
```

instead of --> `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
'packages':['corechart']
});
```

---

next, google's `callback` will wait on the document to load, no need for...

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

---

and `getJSON` is asynchronous
the `loadIngredients` function will return `jsonData` before `getJSON` is finished

as such, recommend loading google first, and waiting for the `callback`,
then load the data, and finally draw the chart

something like the following structure...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: loadIngredients,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function loadIngredients() {
  var jsonData = {
   "cols": [
     {"id":"","label":"Ingredient","pattern":"","type":"string"},
     {"id":"","label":"Amount","pattern":"","type":"number"}
   ],
   "rows": []
  };

  $.getJSON('/api/formula', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, item){
      jsonData.rows.push({"c":[{"v":item.name,"f":null},{"v":item.amount,"f":null}]});
    });
    drawChart(jsonData);
  });
}

function drawChart(jsonData) {
  var options = {
    'title': 'Formula Breakdown By Weight',
    'pieHole': 0.4
  };

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('formula-chart-div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```